# iterate and read json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've got a json response

```
{"profits":{"1":"0,00","2":"0,00","3":"0,00","4":"0,00","5":"0,00","6":"0,00","7":"1.582,64","8":"0,00","9":"0,00","10":"1.500,00","11":"6.000,00","12":"0,00"},"costs":{"1":"0,00","2":"0,00","3":"0,00","4":"100,00","5":"0,00","6":"0,00","7":"0,00","8":"0,00","9":"0,00","10":"123,14","11":"826,45","12":"0,00"},"result":{"1":"0,00","2":"0,00","3":"0,00","4":"-100,00","5":"0,00","6":"0,00","7":"1.582,64","8":"0,00","9":"0,00","10":"1.376,86","11":"5.173,55","12":"0,00"},"total_profits":"9.082,64","total_costs":"1.049,59","total":"8.033,05"}
```

I need the value of the seventh key of profits. I tried this:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(json.profits.7);
```

but then I get an unexpected number in my console log. How can I fix it?

Comment: Bracket notation. `json.profits['7']` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation

Comment: `json.profits[7]` perhaps?

Comment: `7` isn't a valid object property name in javascript. you'll have to use `json.profits['7']`

Comment: I tried json.profits['7'] but then I get the error Unexpected token o

Comment: sounds like you might be parsing an object instead of a string

Comment: removed the line var json = $.parseJSON(data); and used data.profits['7'] and that worked! Thnx guys

Comment: dandavis is correct - parseJSON is for converting a string into JSON, where as the object you have above is already an object. Try data.profits['7']

Answer (score 1):

Works fine with `json.profits['7']`

```js
var json = {
  "profits": {
    "1": "0,00",
    "2": "0,00",
    "3": "0,00",
    "4": "0,00",
    "5": "0,00",
    "6": "0,00",
    "7": "1.582,64",
    "8": "0,00",
    "9": "0,00",
    "10": "1.500,00",
    "11": "6.000,00",
    "12": "0,00"
  },
  "costs": {
    "1": "0,00",
    "2": "0,00",
    "3": "0,00",
    "4": "100,00",
    "5": "0,00",
    "6": "0,00",
    "7": "0,00",
    "8": "0,00",
    "9": "0,00",
    "10": "123,14",
    "11": "826,45",
    "12": "0,00"
  },
  "result": {
    "1": "0,00",
    "2": "0,00",
    "3": "0,00",
    "4": "-100,00",
    "5": "0,00",
    "6": "0,00",
    "7": "1.582,64",
    "8": "0,00",
    "9": "0,00",
    "10": "1.376,86",
    "11": "5.173,55",
    "12": "0,00"
  },
  "total_profits": "9.082,64",
  "total_costs": "1.049,59",
  "total": "8.033,05"
};

alert(json.profits['7']);
```